# Not able to get data from oracle server to System.Data.DataTable

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am calling below query from my vb.net application to oracle server and same query got executed on my oracle sql developer and gives result properly. But when same query is called from vb.net code as below, the result comes with zero rows in data table without any exception.

Thanks in advance.

Oracle

```
with sdk as (select roll_no from student where roll_no='1001';)
select * from sdk;
```

VB

```
Dim MyconnectionString As String = &quot;provider=MSDAORA.1;data source=student;user id=ss;password=1234;
Dim myOleDbConnection As New OleDbConnection(MyconnectionString)

Dim loDataTable As New DataTable
Dim loCommand As New OleDbCommand
Dim loDataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter

loCommand.CommandText = "with sdk as (select roll_no from student where roll_no=&#39;1001&#39;)select * from sdk;"                
loCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text
loCommand.Connection = myOleDbConnection
loCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
loDataAdapter.SelectCommand = loCommand
loDataAdapter.Fill(loDataTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different queries:

```
with sdk as (select roll_no from student where roll_no='1001';)
```

vs

```
with sdk as (select roll_no from student where roll_no='1005')
```

so I guess you have data for roll_no = 1001, but not for roll_no = 1005

Comment: thanks,I update the question its not about the query..i already mention that the  same query got executed on my oracle sql developer and giving result but while calling from app not returning any rows.